# ¿Como uso el modo ajax de select2 con <optgroup> and <option>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Siguiendo [la documentación](https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-optgroup-tags-be-made-selectable) intento lo siguiente:

```js
var data = {
  "results": [
    {
      "text": "Life Good",
      "children": "[{\"id\" : 1, \"text\" : \"Lg Prueba 1\", \"element\" : \"HTMLOptionElement\"}, {\"id\" : 2, \"text\" : \"Lg Prueba 2\", \"element\" : \"HTMLOptionElement\"}]",
      "elment": HTMLOptGroupElement
    },
    {
      "text": "Samsung",
      "children": "[{\"id\" : 3, \"text\" : \"Samsung Prueba 1\", \"element\" : \"HTMLOptionElement\"}, {\"id\" : 4, \"text\" : \"Samsung Prueba 2\", \"element\" : \"HTMLOptionElement\"}]",
      "elment": HTMLOptGroupElement
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": false
  }
};


$("select").select2({
  placeholder: "Elija...",
  allowClear: true,
  data: data.results,
  templateResult: function (data) {    
    // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
    if (!data.element) {
      return data.text;
    }

    var $element = $(data.element);

    var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
    $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

    $wrapper.text(data.text);

    return $wrapper;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width: 100%"></select>
```

Pero no me muestra los hijos, los cuales son reflejados en el `json` como `children`.

[Acá un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820215/selectable-optgroups-in-select2#30948247) de lo que quiero pero no es con ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución fue modificar el código que generaba en PHP los datos para ser enviados al navegador y hacer una decodificación del JSON devuelto por la base de datos para poder integrarse con el resto de datos de PHP que son posteriormente convertidos a JSON:

```
<?php
/* Reproducimos los datos obtenidos de la base de datos */
$valores = [
    0 => (object)[
        'text' => 'Life Good',
        'children' => '[{"id" : 1, "text" : "Lg Prueba 1"}, {"id" : 2, "text" : "Lg Prueba 2"}]',
    ],
    1 => (object)[
        'text' => 'Samsung',
        'children' => '[{"id" : 3, "text" : "Samsung Prueba 1"}, {"id" : 4, "text" : "Samsung Prueba 2"}]',
    ],
];
?><h3>ANTES:</h3>
<pre><?= htmlspecialchars(
  json_encode($valores, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
) ?></pre>
<?php
foreach($valores as $clave => $elemento) {
    $valores[$clave]->children = json_decode($valores[$clave]->children);
}
?><h3>DESPUÉS:</h3>
<pre><?= htmlspecialchars(
  json_encode($valores, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
) ?></pre>
```

Dando como resultado:

```
ANTES:
[
    {
        "text": "Life Good",
        "children": "[{\"id\" : 1, \"text\" : \"Lg Prueba 1\"}, {\"id\" : 2, \"text\" : \"Lg Prueba 2\"}]"
    },
    {
        "text": "Samsung",
        "children": "[{\"id\" : 3, \"text\" : \"Samsung Prueba 1\"}, {\"id\" : 4, \"text\" : \"Samsung Prueba 2\"}]"
    }
]

DESPUÉS:
[
    {
        "text": "Life Good",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "text": "Lg Prueba 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "text": "Lg Prueba 2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Samsung",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "text": "Samsung Prueba 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "text": "Samsung Prueba 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

El trabajo se realiza en el siguiente bucle tras la obtención de los datos:

```
foreach($valores as $clave => $elemento) {
    $valores[$clave]->children = json_decode($valores[$clave]->children);
}
```

En el que decodificamos los datos del campo `children` de cada registro devuelto para que pasen de ser un texto normal a datos reales que puedan ser tratados como tales más adelante por el `json_encode` que envía el contenido al código javascript que se ejecutará en el navegador.

---

**Respuesta original**

Tienes los datos `children` codificados en JSON como cadena. O bien usas un [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) para convertirlos de vuelta en datos reales o bien lo haces manualmente de la siguiente manera:

```js
var data = {
  "results": [
    {
      "text": "Life Good",
      "children": [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "text" : "Lg Prueba 1",
          "element" : HTMLOptionElement
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "text" : "Lg Prueba 2",
          "element" : HTMLOptionElement
        }
      ],
      "element": HTMLOptGroupElement
    },
    {
      "text": "Samsung",
      "children": [
        {
          "id" : 3,
          "text" : "Samsung Prueba 1",
          "element" : HTMLOptionElement
        },
        {
          "id" : 4,
          "text" : "Samsung Prueba 2",
          "element" : HTMLOptionElement
        }
      ],
      "element": HTMLOptGroupElement
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": false
  }
};


$("select").select2({
  placeholder: "Elija...",
  allowClear: true,
  data: data.results,
  templateResult: function (data) {    
    // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
    if (!data.element) {
      return data.text;
    }

    var $element = $(data.element);

    var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
    $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

    $wrapper.text(data.text);

    return $wrapper;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width: 100%"></select>
```

---

**Ejemplo volcando el JSON directamente desde la base de datos**

Si no realizas ningún tipo de escapado [del resultado que obtienes de la base de datos](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/12), puedes usar la información obtenida de manera directa.

```js
var data = {
  "results": [
    {
      "text": "Life Good",
      "children": [{"id":1,"text":"LG-001"},{"id":2,"text":"LG-002"},{"id":3,"text":"LG-003"}],
      "element": HTMLOptGroupElement
    },
    {
      "text": "Samsung",
      "children": [{"id":4,"text":"Sam-004"},{"id":5,"text":"Sam-005"},{"id":6,"text":"Sam-006"}],
      "element": HTMLOptGroupElement
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": false
  }
};


$("select").select2({
  placeholder: "Elija...",
  allowClear: true,
  data: data.results,
  templateResult: function (data) {    
    // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
    if (!data.element) {
      return data.text;
    }

    var $element = $(data.element);

    var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
    $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

    $wrapper.text(data.text);

    return $wrapper;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width: 100%"></select>
```

---

**Ejemplo usando `JSON.parse()` de las cadenas obtenidas de la base de datos**

Si escapas la cadena (o usas `json_encode` o funciones similares en el lado del servidor) [en el resultado que obtienes de la base de datos](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/12), debes usar `JSON.parse()` para volver a convertir los datos en útiles para javascript.

```js
var data = {
  "results": [
    {
      "text": "Life Good",
      "children": JSON.parse("[{\"id\":1,\"text\":\"LG-001\"},{\"id\":2,\"text\":\"LG-002\"},{\"id\":3,\"text\":\"LG-003\"}]"),
      "element": HTMLOptGroupElement
    },
    {
      "text": "Samsung",
      "children": JSON.parse("[{\"id\":4,\"text\":\"Sam-004\"},{\"id\":5,\"text\":\"Sam-005\"},{\"id\":6,\"text\":\"Sam-006\"}]"),
      "element": HTMLOptGroupElement
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": false
  }
};


$("select").select2({
  placeholder: "Elija...",
  allowClear: true,
  data: data.results,
  templateResult: function (data) {    
    // We only really care if there is an element to pull classes from
    if (!data.element) {
      return data.text;
    }

    var $element = $(data.element);

    var $wrapper = $('<span></span>');
    $wrapper.addClass($element[0].className);

    $wrapper.text(data.text);

    return $wrapper;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width: 100%"></select>
```

Comment: ¿Como hago si el json lo traigo asi de la `db`?

Comment: Entonces hay que usar `JSON.parse()`. Te voy a poner un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo así.

Comment: [Acá la demostración](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/12) de como consulto a la `db`.

Comment: Ya está, mira los resultados. ¿Qué usas en el lado del servidor para enviar esa información al navegador?

Comment: `json_encode` el `json` que obtengo del lado del cliente es el que coloque en la pregunta. ¿Como puedo insertarle el `JSON.parse()` a cada `children`?

Comment: No necesitas usar `json_encode` en PHP porque usas `json_build_object/json_agg` en SQL, de modo que los datos que obtienes ya son JSON, no necesitas hacer doble conversión. Envíalos al navegador con un `<?= $datos ?>` o `<?php echo $datos ?>` y no es necesario hacer doble conversión en un sentido y uno adicional en el opuesto. Edito: Si agregas el bucle en PHP que genera el código javascript puedo modificártelo para que haga la tarea correctamente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58436/discussion-between-pablo-contreras-and-oscargarcia).